# How to pass a dynamicy changed model to Partial view?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a list of "workbooks" displayed in a table. Each workbook has a "Share" button next to the workbook's title. When the user clicks on the share button a modal dialog is shown containing a form.

The form allows the user to enter a list of the recipient's emails separated by a comma which is validated on the client-side.

As the dialog is located in a partial view `_ShareView.cshtml` that allows me to pass a modal `WorkbookShareModel` that has some fields like `WorkbookId` and `Title`. The goal here is to pass the details of each workbook when the user presses the share button (i.e. construct a modal and pass it to the already rendered model).

I am not sure how to pass a model to an already rendered view?

The solution have to be done on the client (i.e. dont involve actions on the server that return the partial view provided the parameters are passed). I want to avoid unnesessary calls to the server - we have all the data on the client regarding a workbook and I need to do a POST when the user types in list of emails.

This is my index.cshtml:

```
@section BodyFill
{
<div id="shareFormContainer">
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ShareView", new WorkbookShareModel());}
</div>

<div class="landing-container">
    <div class="workbook-container">

            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                @foreach (var workbook in Model.Workbooks)
                {
                    string trClassName, linkText;
                    if (workbook.Metadata.SharedBy == null)
                    {
                        trClassName = "saved-workbooks";
                        linkText = workbook.Name;
                    } else {
                        trClassName = "shared-with-me";
                        linkText = string.Format(
                            BaseLanguage.SharedWithMeWorkbook, 
                            workbook.Name, 
                            workbook.Metadata.SharedBy,
                            workbook.Metadata.SharedDate.ToShortDateString()
                        );
                    }

                    <tr class="@trClassName">
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink(linkText, "Open", "OpenAnalytics", new { id = Model.Id, workbook = workbook.Name })</td>
                        <td class="last-modified-date" title="Last Modified Date">@workbook.ModifiedDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td class="share">
                            <button title="Share" class="share-button" onclick='showSharingView("@workbook.Name", "@workbook.Id", "@Model.Id")'>&nbsp;</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts
    {
    <!--Load JQuery 'unobtrusive' validation -->
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // hide the modal as soon as the page loads
    $('#shareFormModal').modal("hide");

        function showSharingView(title, workbookId, id) {
            $('#shareFormModal').modal("show");

            // how to pass a WorkbookShareModel to my partial view from here?
        }

        function hideDialog() {
            var form = $("#partialform");
            // only hide the dialog if the form is valid
            if (form.valid()) {
                activateShareButtons();
                $('#shareFormModal').modal("hide");
            }
        }


        // Helper method that validates list of emails
        function IsEmailValid(emailList, element, parameters) {
            var SPLIT_REGEXP = /[,;\s]\s*/;
            var EMAIL_REGEXP =
                /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@@[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)+$/i;

            var emails = emailList.split(SPLIT_REGEXP);
            for (var i = emails.length; i--;) {
                if (!EMAIL_REGEXP.test(emails[i].trim())) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    </script>
}
```

That is my dialog:

```
@using DNAAnalysisCore.Resources
@model DNAAnalysisCore.Models.WorkbookShareModel
@* Partial view that contains the 'Share Workbook dialog' modal *@

<!-- Modal -->
<div onclick="activateShareButtons()" class="modal fade" id="shareFormModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Share Workbook - @Model.Title</h4>

            </div>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("ShareWorkbook", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "partialform" }))
            {
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <label>@BaseLanguage.Share_workbook_Instruction_text</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Emails" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="@BaseLanguage.ShareDialogPlaceholder"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Emails" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <input asp-for="Title" />
                    <input asp-for="Id" />
                    <input asp-for="WorkbookId"/>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button onclick="hideDialog()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Share</button>
                    <button onclick="activateShareButtons()" id="btnCancelDialog" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to solve your problem :

**Option 1 :**

Since you have got the parameters(title, workbookId, id) , you can call server side function using AJAX to render the partial view  , then replace the DIV contained in the partial view with the updated contents in the callback function of AJAX .

You can click [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51913.asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-load-a-partial-view.aspx#Load_partial_view_from_javascript_method) for code sample .

**Option 2 :**

Directly update related input/area using Jquery . For example , the input tag helper :

```
<input asp-for="<Expression Name>">
```

generates the id and name HTML attributes for the expression name specified in the asp-for attribute. So you can set the value using Jquery like :

```
$("#Title").val("Title")
```

Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for Tag Helpers in forms in ASP.NET Core

With Option 2 , you need to clear the `Emails` area firstly after user click the share button ; With Option 1 , you don't need to care that since the HTML will replace entirely .

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I much prefer option 2 as I don't need to do 2 calls to the server. Currently, the project I am working on have OP1 implemented but I am trying to get rid of the 1st call that renders the dialog.

I will try it OP2 and see if I will manage to get it working